# Highlight State in Choropleth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am following this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/ElefHead/ebff082d41ef8b9658059c408096f782

However, I am not understanding why when I simply draw 3 things (counties, states, state borders). When a state is hovered, I just want to change the fill color and have the experience be smooth.

jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kick_out/jq3w6xft/10/

The current code has a similar css style as the bl.ocks example: When i remove the county part, i get no highlighting.

```
.county-boundary:hover, .state:hover {
  fill: orange
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the states' class is `state`, not `states`. But this question is not just a *typo* question, there is a bigger issue here:

You set the states' fill to `none` (using their parent group CSS). That's why you hover has no effect. In an SVG, the default `pointer-events` value is `visiblePainted`, [in which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> The element can only be the target of a pointer event when the visibility property is set to visible and e.g. when a mouse cursor is over the interior (i.e., 'fill') of the element and the fill property is set to a value **other than none**. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, you should set their `pointer-events` to `all`.

Also, if you want to show the counties, change the append order.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
async function drawMap() {
  var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
    .attr("height", 600)
    .attr("width", 1000)

  var map = await d3.json('https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json')
  var path = d3.geoPath()
  var mouseOver = function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
  }
  var mouseOut = function(d) {}
  svg.append("g")
    .attr('id', 'counties')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "county-border")
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr('class', 'states')

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "state")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "county-boundary")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
}
drawMap()
```

```css
#states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 1.9px;
}

#states .active {
  display: none;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
}

#counties {
  fill: none;
}

.county-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-width: 0.7px;
}

.state:hover {
  fill: orange;
}

#sliderContainer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>County Map</title>

  <body>
    <div id="wrap"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The state/states wasnt a typo. I understand the 'class' declaration, but i was still struggling with the .attr('id','states') and how that affects the output and why its there. The pointer-events was lack of knowledge, so i appreciate the lesson.